# Script not able to locate file

Tags: windows, path, scheduled-tasks

I have task scheduler to run every sunday to take backup and copy to ftp server. But script failing with System Error code:2 . However i am able to run script manually successfully.

Comment: Where is the file located? And what is your path for both logged in user (when you manually test it) and for the script (same account, other account. Can you echo the $path to a file and compare it?)

Comment: Path is same for both the case D:\base_backup

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. $PATH (or in batch files I guess $$PATH). As in start cmd and echo $path

Comment: According to your comment, it seems that your script depends on the PATH. However, scripts run through the Task Scheduler have no PATH. Question: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @harrymc yes i m on windows

Comment: I created new task scheduler with same script file and it started working fine. However i compared both task schedulers in xml file noticed that logontype is different in both the cases. For new file logon type is interactive token and old file logon type is S4U . What is difference in both the cases

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your script depends on the PATH.
However, scripts run through the Task Scheduler have no PATH.

You will need to ensure that the full explicit path is given in the script
to every executable that is not part of Windows (meaning does not reside in
`C:\Windows\System32`).